# Web cilent and server communication throught firewall

Tags: java, web-services, gwt, client-server, firewall

I want to create a `web application`, which is divided into two part one is client and another is server.

**Client:**

- Client part is on the shared server.
- Client is the `GWT Application` which only use to display data (containing only ui elements and ui events).
- Client application is used by server to view and present it's own data.

**Server:**

- The server is the simple java `web service` (`restlet`).
- The server is reside behind the `firewall`.
- The server contains actual data.
- There are N number of servers.
- Server does not contains any view if server wants ro view data it will use the gwt client application.
- Every server uses same gwt application to view it's own data.

**Note :**

- **Client does not contains any address of the server. server will send the request to view it's data.**
- **There is no firewall inbound exception on server firewall to access server data from out side client**

I need to communicate client and server through firewall, Is there any architecture or design pattern to implement this type of application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the firewall can bring new restrictions to a GWT application compared with other types of applications (clients).

In case you have the GWT client on one server which makes calls to a different server you might have some issues due to same origin restriction.

This can be resolved in several ways:
- your GWT application has a server-side part which calls the other servers. And your GWT client makes normal RPC / JSON calls to the GWT server side (on the same server).
- in case you want to make directly the call on the different server from your GWT client you can use JSONP or the restygwt library.